# Integrate Dataframe from a Python File to Django

Tags: django, pandas, dataframe

I've developed a complex data analysis model using Python (for the sake of simplicity, let's call it `analysis.py`) which contains multiple long algorithms to transform a set of raw data and spits out output in the form of `dataframe` as well.

I've been looking into some tutorials recently on Django framework and have tried building a simple web app that resembles a forum/blog post web app.

With the `dataframe` output from the `analysis.py`, I would like to display the data in the form of multiple charts on the web app.

Can anyone point me to a direction to move from here? I've looked for multiple resources online but I think I am unable to find the correct keywords that match with what I actually want to build. I just want a shell code kind of a thing to integrate into my current django backend in order to be able to call the `dataframe` from the `analysis.py`

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: better write out what you have done so far in django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It amazes me somehow that after posting a question here, I managed to come up with better keywords in finding the solution that is closely matched to my intended product.

Again, I would like to apologize if my question was too vague or did not contain any script that I've done so far, since I was merely looking for direction to move forward. And fortunately I did after giving it much thought and integrating different solutions from multiple sources on the net.

I'm not sure if my solution is the best solution, but it works for me and if it at least helps other people who were on the same boat as I did before, I'd be glad!

So my solution entails importing a dataframe from the analysis.py and then pass the data that I want as API Endpoints (using Django Rest Framework) in order to be displayed in my dashboard.

The following are some details (with some scripts) of my solution:

views.py

```
# Importing the external python script (analysis.py). 
#This is where the data from csv is imported and is transformed. 
#The script is written in a function form and returns the dataframe. 

from . import analysis
from .analysis import data_transform

#Django Rest Framework
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

class ChartData(APIView):
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes =[]
    def get(self, request, format=None):   

        # Assign dataframe output to a new dataframe
        df = data_transform()
        # Assigning variables from datafram
        data1 = df['VOL'].values.tolist()
        data2 = df['PRICE'].values.tolist()
        data = {
            "data1":data1,
            "data2":data2,
            }

        #Return endpoints in Json format
        return Response(data)
```

Analysis.py looks more like this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def data_transform()
    #where all the transformations happened
    return dataframe
```

And then I passed the endpoints ('data') to a html in order to visualize them using chart.js. You can find some good resources in the Tube. Look up keywords chart.js and django.

Again, I'm not sure this is the best method. I am open to a better solution, if you guys have any!